# MVC ActionLink 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi Guys' I am getting HTTP 404 in my MVC project and I am not sure where it is coming from.

On the _NavBar I have an ActionLink control that is calling to CreateSite

```
<li>
  @Html.ActionLink("Create Location","CreateSite", "SiteRegistration", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
</li>
```

I have an Controller name SiteRegistrationController

```
public class SiteRegistrationController : Controller
{
    SiteInfoManager manager = new SiteInfoManager();
    //
    // GET: /SiteRegistration/
    public ActionResult UserSiteResult()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The views I have are Folder SiteRegistration and CreateSite.cshtml.

The Error is coming from the SiteInfoManager line in the Controller.
Any help would be great.

Comment: You do not have an action  method called `CreateSite` , but your action method is trying to use that (second param). change that to `UserSiteResult`

Comment: @Shyju Do you mean something like this  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserSiteResult(SiteRegistration registration)
        {

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Create Location","UserSiteResult", "SiteRegistration", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })`

Comment: @Shyju thanks but I am still getting the 404, I changed the action link to <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Location","UserSiteResult", "SiteRegistration", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li> and in the views folder I now have SiteRegistration/ UserSiteResult.cshtml. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your @Html.ActionLink to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Location","UserSiteResult", "SiteRegistration", new { id = "registerLink" }, null)
```

And update your Controller:

```
public ActionResult UserSiteResult(string id)
{
    // you can use id now, as it will be regirsterLink
    return View();
}
```